# Can I mix sessions auth and token auth in one site?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have django application using sessions auth. I need to add API part. This API will be used by my app.users only (web browsers and mobiles devices as well). I would prefer to use token auth for API as it seems more robust. I found [rest_framework_jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) that can handle it. 
My question: Can I mix sessions auth for web and token auth for API in one site without problems?
I think about the web app and the API app as two different applications. So I want to separate them in my project, use different subdomain and use different kind of auth for each. Is it possible to separate auth by subdomain? I would like to send token when user log in to web app. Is it good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you see in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication), you can configure multiple authentication backends without any problems. DRF will just try each one of the backends until one says "ok".

One thing to keep in mind: 
If you (for example) provide an invalid JSON-Web-Token then the authentication will immediately fail and other backends will not be tried. Good to see in the [source of rest_framework_jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py#L29).

```
def authenticate(self, request):
    """
    Returns a two-tuple of `User` and token if a valid signature has been
    supplied using JWT-based authentication.  Otherwise returns `None`.
    """
    auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

    if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b'jwt':
        return None

    if len(auth) == 1:
        msg = 'Invalid JWT header. No credentials provided.'
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
    elif len(auth) > 2:
        msg = ('Invalid JWT header. Credentials string '
               'should not contain spaces.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    try:
        payload = jwt_decode_handler(auth[1])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
        msg = 'Signature has expired.'
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
    except jwt.DecodeError:
        msg = 'Error decoding signature.'
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    user = self.authenticate_credentials(payload)

    return (user, auth[1])
```

- `return None` means the backend saying: "this is not JWT, let the others try
- `raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)` means: "the user tried JWT, but the he failed it."

To answer the further questions:

- no need for doing this in separate applications (but it's no problem if you want).
- as you can read in ["setting the authentication scheme"](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#setting-the-authentication-scheme) you can define global defaults for authentication backends, but you can also override them per `View` or `ViewSet`.